# Why is ParseException shown for SimpleDateFormat even when correct pattern is followed?

Tags: java, date-parsing, parseexception

Inside a jsp file, I have passed an element of input type="date" and I want to insert that element to the column of type Date inside the database.
When I pass this,

```
<input type="date" class="well well-sm" id="startDate" name="startDate">
```

and receive it inside the servlet as:

```
String date=request.getParameter("startDate");
p.setFromDate(date);
```

When I printed the date, I'm getting `2018-05-24` which is the input I'm passing, which is in the required 'yyyy-MM-dd' format. I'm getting this date inside another class in the below format:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.util.Date ufromdate=sdf1.parse(p.getFromDate());//p.getFromDate()returns a string which has been assigned the value passed from the input element of type date.
java.sql.Date sqlfromdate=new java.sql.Date(ufromdate.getTime());
ps.setDate(5,sqlfromdate );
```

Here I'm getting `ParseException` even though I followed the correct pattern given as a reference in other answers written for similar questions in StackOverflow. I'm still getting this exception.

Comment: "returns a string which has been assigned the value passed from the input element of type date." And what is the actual content of that string? I bet you a tenner it's not in the yyyy-MM-dd format.

Comment: usually it is that hidden whitespace. try trimming

Comment: Add the input you're passing in. Also may need to mention your Locale. Please see [mcve]

Comment: @AndyTurner It is in yyyy-MM-dd format. I have updated the question.Please check.

Comment: maybe this is a locale thing. i can't reproduce this problem, even when adding spaces to beginning and end like Jigar speculated.

Comment: "When I printed the date:I'm getting 2018-05-24 " are you printing `date` or `p.getFromDate()`?

Comment: @NathanHughes Updated the question with input. Please check.

Comment: @AndyTurner I printed that date inside the servlet, so I'm getting that value for date.

Comment: @HayreFkru but you're not parsing `date`, you are parsing `p.getFromDate()`. Are they the same? I don't know. I assume they're not, otherwise you could just use `date` directly.

Comment: Add this line just before calling `sdf1.parse`: `if (!"2018-05-24".equals(p.getFromDate())) throw new RuntimeException("["+p.getFromDate()+"]");` (just for debugging purposes).

Comment: @AndyTurner No they are not the same. One is a string I'm passing as  to a function using setter, p.setFromDate(date);p.getFromDate() is a getter returning a String.

Comment: @HayreFkru so, if they are different, what is the value of `p.getFromDate()`?

Comment: @LittleSanti No difference, still shows the same parsetype exception.

Comment: @AndyTurner I just printed p.getFromDate() below the setter, p.setFromDate(date) and I got 2018-05-24.

Comment: @HayreFkru did you check with same method with exact date string?
sdf1.parse("2018-05-24"); // if it works then the problem is p.getFromDate() value.... maybe you have to cast this value into String or trim unnecessary spaces.

Comment: How many lives the holy debugger saved...

Comment: @Amit The value is already stored as a String.p.getFromDate() returns a string.

Comment: I just told you that check with String str = (String) p.getFromDate().trim();
Its for debugging...

Comment: @HayreFkru This seems nonsense. Please post the complete stack trace error, and pay attention to the line numbers.

Comment: It sounds weird, but there’s an explanation somewhere, of course. `ParseException` has a `getErrorOffset` method. What does it return? Also, as has been said, please add the stacktrace in the question (format it as code).

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Use a `LocalDate` and its one-arg `parse` method and you won’t need a formatter.

Comment: You may also want to add something like `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p.getFromDate().toCharArray()));` and show us the output from it.